# Trying to fire a ui-modal on a 401 server response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to fire a login modal anytime the server responds with a 401 status code. Based on this guide https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/7bbf0346acec I've created a status code interceptor like this.

```
// intercept http status codes
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$injector', function ($injector) {
        return $injector.get('AuthInterceptor');
    }]);
});

app.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q) {
    return {
        responseError: function (res) {
            if (res.status === 401) {
                console.log('AuthInterceptor says you are not authorized');
            }
            if (res.status === 404) {
                console.log('AuthInterceptor says this page is not found');
            }
            return $q.reject(res);
        }
    };
});
```

When I try to inject my AuthInterceptor factory with $modal I get a circular dependency error. What is a good practice for triggering a $modal from something like this? The guide that I linked used this AuthInterceptor factory to broadcast 'Auth_events', which were simply constant strings. They didn't show any use of these auth_events beyond broadcasting them so I don't understand how they're suppose to work. In addition to my main question can anyone clarify what these auth events do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a circular dependency error since the `$modal` service has dependency on `$http`. This is a common problem with `$http` interceptors that got dependency on `$http` themselves. Fortunately the remedy is simple: you need to inject `$injector` into your interceptor and retrieve `$model` from the injector like so:

```
 app.factory('AuthInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $injector) {
    return {
        responseError: function (res) {

            var $modal = $injector.get('$modal');

            if (res.status === 401) {
                //you can use $modal here...
                console.log('AuthInterceptor says you are not authorized');
            }
            if (res.status === 404) {
                console.log('AuthInterceptor says this page is not found');
            }
            return $q.reject(res);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and gave me a better understanding of the circular dependency that was happening. Do you have any tips on checking if a modal is currently open? For an example involving this http interceptor. I have a modal login form. Thanks to you I can now open this modal whenever a 401 status code is intercepted. The login form itself will send a 401 status code when invalid credentials are entered and will then stack a new login modal atop the original. How might I avoid this?